# OrientDB Server partly ignores ORIENTDB_HOME

Tags: java, java-7, orientdb

I'm trying to start an embedded OrientDB server. I set the `ORIENTDB_HOME` to a folder that contains the `config/` and `plugins/` folders. I also included my config file in the classpath, because the server didn't seem to load my config file even though it has the default name.

Now it does start and apply my config, however apparently the application directory is used as `ORIENTDB_HOME`, because my plugins aren't loaded and the database is created there instead of where I want it to.

This is my code:

```
public void startServer() {
    try {
        System.setProperty("ORIENTDB_HOME", "C:\\my\\orientdb_home\\path");

        server = OServerMain.create(true);
        // server.startup(); // this doesn't load the correct config
        server.startup(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/orientdb-server-config.xml")); // workaround
        server.activate();

        OServerNetworkListener httpListener = server.getListenerByProtocol(server.getNetworkProtocols().get("binary"));
        binaryPort = httpListener.getInboundAddr().getPort();
        httpListener = server.getListenerByProtocol(server.getNetworkProtocols().get("http"));
        httpPort = httpListener.getInboundAddr().getPort();

        System.out.println("Started OrientDB Server.\nBinary Port is " + binaryPort + "\nHTTP Port is " + httpPort);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The fascinating thing is that the log output clearly says it's using the correct directory for the databases, but it doesn't do so.

```
2019-06-14 09:32:23:556 INFO  Loading configuration from input stream [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2019-06-14 09:32:23:731 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.2.37 (build a7541e7ceeabf592dd9a7b2928b6c023cbc73193, branch 2.2.x) is starting up... [OServer]
2019-06-14 09:32:23:741 INFO  Databases directory: C:\my\orientdb_home\path\databases [OServer]
2019-06-14 09:32:23:830 INFO  Configuration of usage of soft references inside of containers of results of SQL execution [OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer]
2019-06-14 09:32:23:831 INFO  Initial or maximum values of heap memory usage are NOT set, containers of results of SQL executors will NOT use soft references by default [OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer]
2019-06-14 09:32:23:832 INFO  Auto configuration of disk cache size. [OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer]
2019-06-14 09:32:23:919 INFO  17066577920 B/16275 MB/15 GB of physical memory were detected on machine [ONative]
2019-06-14 09:32:23:919 INFO  Detected memory limit for current process is 17066577920 B/16275 MB/15 GB [ONative]
2019-06-14 09:32:23:921 INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=3,618MB (heap=3,618MB direct=3,618MB os=16,275MB) [OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer]
2019-06-14 09:32:23:922 INFO  Lowering disk cache size from 3,618MB to 3,616MB. [OGlobalConfiguration]
2019-06-14 09:32:24:117 INFO  Listening binary connections on 127.0.0.1:2424 (protocol v.36, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2019-06-14 09:32:24:120 INFO  Listening http connections on 127.0.0.1:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2019-06-14 09:32:25:081 INFO  Storage 'plocal:databases/pvRelations' is created under OrientDB distribution : 2.2.37 (build a7541e7ceeabf592dd9a7b2928b6c023cbc73193, branch 2.2.x) [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2019-06-14 09:32:27:607 INFO  {db=pvRelations} -> Loaded plocal database 'pvRelations' [OServer]
2019-06-14 09:32:27:609 INFO  Found ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD variable, using this value as root's password [OServer]
2019-06-14 09:32:27:621 INFO  ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator is active [ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator]
2019-06-14 09:32:27:623 INFO  OServerConfigAuthenticator is active [OServerConfigAuthenticator]
2019-06-14 09:32:27:625 INFO  OSystemUserAuthenticator is active [OSystemUserAuthenticator]
2019-06-14 09:32:27:634 INFO  Installed GREMLIN language v.2.6.0 - graph.pool.max=50 [OGraphServerHandler]
2019-06-14 09:32:27:638 WARNI Authenticated clients can execute any kind of code into the server by using the following allowed languages: [sql] [OServerSideScriptInterpreter]
2019-06-14 09:32:27:638 INFO  OrientDB Studio available at http://127.0.0.1:2480/studio/index.html [OServer]
2019-06-14 09:32:27:638 INFO  OrientDB Server is active v2.2.37 (build a7541e7ceeabf592dd9a7b2928b6c023cbc73193, branch 2.2.x). [OServer]
```

To clarify again: The directory `C:\my\orientdb_home\path\databases` isn't used, instead it's `path\to\my\application\databases`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I tell the server to use the directory of my choice to search for config and plugins as well as store the databases?

EDIT:
I just noticed that in fact the databases directory is used, but only for the OSystem database. My own database is stored at the wrong location. I defined it in my config file:

```
...
<storages>
    <storage name="myDB" path="plocal:databases/myDB" userName="admin" userPassword="admin" loaded-at-startup="true" />
</storages>
...
```

EDIT2:
So I noticed, the wrong database location is due to the manually configured storage path in the config file. However, this still doesn't explain why I need to directly provide my config file and why my plugins (OrientDB Studio) aren't loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I should have read the server.bat more carefully. While setting `ORIENTDB_HOME` apparently does set the default database directory, the default config file isn't located under `%ORIENTDB_HOME%\config\orientdb-server-config.xml`. I had to set the environment variable `orientdb.config.file`.

My plugin wasn't loaded because it didn't reside in the plugins folder, but was included to my classpath, which apparently isn't enough.